# Render object with only shadow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I have this image (the background is transparent):

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to only render the shadow of the ball, while rendering the rest of the ball transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this directly in the 3D scene as far as I know. You are probably looking for a "Shadow Catcher" type of material, but this is currently not supported in Blender Cycles yet. [There are plans to add it in the future](https://developer.blender.org/D1788) but nothing that works currently.

The only way I know to achieve this currently, is in post production through compositing, using the image you show as a mask to mix it over another image in the *Blender Compositor*
Use it as an inverted mask where dark areas are more opaque as opposed to white areas being more transparent as shown bellow.

[image: Compositor shadow]