# Material that can catch shadows but wont cast itself

Tags: mesh, materials, transparency, tracking

Is it possible to create material in blender that can catch/stop shadows without generating itself a shadow? So far i have used material called holdout, but this material is still generating weird shading effects.[image]

As you can see this material can catch well shadows but it itself leavs an ugly shadow. So how can I create a material witch can catch shadow (as this material did) and not cast itself a shadow. If some of you can give me answer I would be very thankful :)

Comment: Try to turn of the 'Shadow' checkbox under the Object > Cycles Settings in the properties tab.

Comment: You are looking for a [Shadow Catcher material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52555/render-object-with-only-shadow/52562#52562) which is not yet available in Blender as of version 2.78 but is planed for 2.79 onwards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use the Input > Light Path node like so:

[image: shadow light path test]

If the cycles ray is a shadow ray, use the transparent BSDF, otherwise use the Diffuse node (or whatever material nodes you want).

The grey cube casts a shadow on the plane and the blue cube, but the blue cube casts no shadow.

Comment: Thx I'll try...